# Android : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 52

Tags: java, android, gson, android-volley

I get a json response returned by a web service.

```
{
   "status":{
      "msg":"success",
      "code":0
   },
   "timezones":[
      [
         "US/Eastern",
         "(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time"
      ],
      [
         "US/Central",
         "(UTC-06:00) Central Time"
      ],
      [
         "US/Mountain",
         "(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time"
      ],
      [
         "US/Pacific",
         "(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time"
      ],
      [
         "US/Alaska",
         "(UTC-09:00) Alaska"
      ],
      [
         "US/Hawaii",
         "(UTC-10:00) Hawaii"
      ]
   ]
}
```

I am parsing this using gson.

```
public class TimeZonesResult 
{
    public ApiStatus status;

    @SerializedName("timezones")
    public JsonArray arrTimeZones;
}
```

ApiStatus is another class where I declare msg and code.
But I have problem parsing timezones. 
I get "Android : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 52 " returned by volley. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems Timezones is an array of array.

Comment: Yes. my bad. changed it to List<List<String>> and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `List<List<String>>` as the data type for arrTimeZones instead of a `JsonArray`. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ is a good resource for getting pojo representations of your json data correct.